# Convert seconds to HH:MM:SS with String.Format

Tags: c#, timespan

I have a `float` that is an amount of seconds, I want to make a string in the format `hh:mm:ss` that represent a countdown from 24hours.
I'm trying to use this code:

```
TimeToMissionsReady = 86400f - FromMissionCompletedSeconds;
TimeToMissionsReadyString = string.Format ("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", TimeToMissionsReady / 3600f, (TimeToMissionsReady / 60f) % 60f, TimeToMissionsReady % 60f);

Debug.Log (TimeToMissionsReadyString);
```

but it isn't working 'cause it shows weird stuff like:
24:60:30 and after a second 24:59:29

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at TimeSpan?

Comment: What is the value and type of `TimeToMissionsReady` exactly?

Comment: I don't understand why this output is wrong: "24:60:30 and after a second 24:59:29"

Comment: FromMissionCompletedSeconds must be negative or a very small number.  You are subtracting two float numbers and subtracting a very small number from a larger number can give rounding errors.  You may want to use Math.Round() or cast the subtraction to an integer (int)(86400f - FromMissionCompletedSeconds)

Comment: ok, now i'm using `TimeToMissionsReady = 86400f - FromMissionCompletedSeconds;
  TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeToMissionsReady);
  TimeToMissionsReadyString = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);` and it works great, thanks to everybody, i apoligize for the bad wrinting of the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't *even* told us what is the type and value of `TimeToMissionsReady` exactly and I don't understand the meaning of *24:60:30 and after a second 24:59:29* sentence but the right way to solve your problem seems to using [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan) structure in in .NET Framework.

Let's say your `TimeToMissionsReady` is `86300` as a `float`.

```
float TimeToMissionsReady = 86300f;
```

You can use [`TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double)` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds) to calculate those value.

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(TimeToMissionsReady);
```

[image]

And you can format it with [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
Debug.Log(ts.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss")); // 23:58:20
```

Comment: thank you very much, i'm sorry i didn't explain the problem well.

Comment: @Pitagora Glad to help. You might wanna check [ask] page for that :)

Answer (score 2):

The minutes value is rounded by the Format function.You could do this :

```
string TimeToMissionsReadyString = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", TimeToMissionsReady / 3600f, Math.Truncate((TimeToMissionsReady / 60f)) % 60f, TimeToMissionsReady % 60f);
```

But I believe TimeSpan is much easier to use. Here is a simple example using TimeSpan :

```
 float f = 86400f;
 TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(f);
 string s = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", ((int) t.TotalHours), t.Minutes, t.Seconds);
```

Comment: thank you too, i utilized your "string s" line of code

Comment: I am glad it helped. TimeSpan is really usefull for time value formatting.